# Where is the GAS Gui builder 'resource' stored, and why can't I see the code?

Tags: google-apps-script

The subject of the question says it all.

Where do I find the 'code-behind' or 'resource', or whatever it's referred to as, which is generated when I use the GAS Gui builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code or whatever describes a gui must be stored in the project file (For which up to today there is no way to access its contents either).
 You can open/access the different gui-components from within gui-builder, but only those created inside the actual project (That's why I think its stored in the project file).

Comment: I just noticed that even a script can only be viewed from within the google apps script web based development environment.  Attempts at downloading it from Drive are thwarted at the first screen because the script is not a downloadable object.  WTF, google, you are starting to scare me !

Comment: @SmittyBoy -The GUI builder is a graphical 'front-end' and must be considered as it is... if you want to have a script that describes your UI 'in plain text' then use the script UI elements. That said, I'm wondering why you're asking such questions ? Do you have a question about GAS or do you just want to express your point of vue ?

Comment: @Serge:  Because I wanted to see what code the GUI builder was generating.  Also, I want to be able to work on files while disconnected from the cloud.  So, this is a real issue, not just a point of view

Comment: Oh, I see... and what about taking pictures without a camera or giving a phone call without a phone? GAS runs on the cloud, nothing wrong about writing code offline but don't expect to use it / test it / in an offline environment... there are plenty of other programing languages out there to do that. As stated on this site tag : *Google Apps Script is a JavaScript cloud scripting language*

Comment: OK, I guess that makes sense.  I must realign my preconceptions about developing with this environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the UI built using the GUI builder only by using the GUI builder. The code behind it, if generated, is not exposed.

Comment: It must be stored somewhere, and it is clearly associated with my user account, so why do I not have the ability to view it ?

In fact there is a more fundamental question:  Once I build a UI 'resource' with the Gui builder, and save it, how do I then find it ?  What if I don't remember what I named it ?  It doesn't show up on my Google Drive file list.

Answer (score 0):

GUI components are stored with the script but currently hidden because they are stored in a proprietary model format to make them easily editable in the builder, and not stored as raw code. We should probably give you a way to see the code that gets generated at runtime, but making it editable would be very challenging since not all edits to the code would result in a valid model. But open an issue; we can definitely look into it.

Scripts not downloading in drive is something we are aware of; no promises but it's a known issue.