# Google App Script GUI Builder - get project code?

Tags: google-apps-script, gui-builder

I've done some searching and i cannot believe that NO ONE has asked this same question, so maybe i'm just not using the right words, but HOW does one get the code from the 'component' (or simply.. the gui) that they just created using the Google App Script GUI Builder? Am i missing something here or is this just plain impossible?

Comment: The main reason I need to see the code from my GUI Builder Component is because the list of controls in the builder is incomplete. My goal is to use the GUI Builder to design the aspects that it can and then I finish the rest manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the code to include a GUI builded Ui in your script - and this code is indeed not available (see [Corey's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066041/where-is-the-gas-gui-builder-resource-stored-and-why-cant-i-see-the-code/14071351#14071351)) - but you can modify it or append other elements quite easily as shown in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425999/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-gui-built-with-gui-builder-in-another-panel/13434092#13434092)